# pg_dump for all metadata and only table data of selected tables

Tags: postgresql

I want to create a script that will dump the whole schema and the data of only a few tables and write it to one file.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `--exclude-table-data` option of `pg_dump` to define the tables whose data should be excluded from the dump.

Answer (score 1):

multiple `-t` lists table you want take backup of, eg

```
MacBook-Air:~ vao$ pg_dump -d t -t pg_database -t a -t so | grep 'CREATE TABLE'
CREATE TABLE pg_database (
CREATE TABLE a (
CREATE TABLE so (
```

takes backup of structure and data of three mentioned tables. I use grep to hide other rows and yet give idea of backup contents

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html

> -t table
>
> --table=table
>
> Dump only tables with names matching table. For this purpose, “table”
>   includes views, materialized views, sequences, and foreign tables.
>   Multiple tables can be selected by writing multiple -t switches.